# Python script terminates after calling QgsProject.write()

Tags: pyqgis

Python script using QGIS package terminates suddenly when calling QgsProject.write.
Idea is to create QGIS Project with select list of files and save it to disk, in automated manner.

Script:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsRasterLayer

def foo():
    filePath = "C:/Users/username/Documents/projects/GeoTiffSample.tiff"
    savePAth = "C:/Users/username/Documents/projects/test2.qgs"
    proj = QgsProject.instance()
    proj.setFileName(savePAth)
    testlayer = QgsRasterLayer(filePath, baseName = "testLayer")
    proj.addMapLayer(testlayer)
    proj.setFileName(savePAth)
    proj.setDirty(True)
    try:
        print("Prewrite")
        ret = proj.write()
        print("Postwrite")
        pass
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)
    print(ret) 

print("START")
try:
    foo()
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
print("END")
```

Output:

```
START
Prewrite
```

Documentation is kind of lacking on any info. I suspect unhandeled exception in QGIS library.

Comment: Do you run your code from the QGIS Python Console or in a standalone script? Answer should vary with the context

Comment: If you use it standalone, it could be te call of `QgsProject.instance()`. As I understand, instance() is used for projects opened inside of QGIS. See here: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsProject.html.

Comment: It would be useful to know which version of QGIS you are using

Comment: ThomasG77, indeed it does. Thx, your comment encouraged me to double check documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Double checked documentation and cookbook (https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#pythonapplications) "Using PyQGIS in custom applications".
The I simply needed to initiate QGIS app.

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsRasterLayer, QgsApplication

#Optional line: QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/path/to/qgis/installation", True)
#I don't have qgis installed and simply using pyqgis package, so line was ommited

qgs = QgsApplication([],True)
qgs.initQgis() #initiate QGIS

#Enter your code here

qgs.exitQgis() #free resources
```

Problem solved. But it would be rather nice of developer to add error message.